# Fear was traded

Tags: riddle, haiku

> At first we feared her.
>   Now she fears us, the killers.
>   We'll die together.

Who are we and who is she?

Hint:

> She will die with us too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is she

> Mother Nature?

At first we feared her.

> At first we feared fire, earthquakes, the sea, waves, pretty much everything we didn't understand about nature (well we still fear a lot of these things)

Now she fears us, the killers.

> We are slowly killing nature, the child/creation of Mother Nature

We'll die together.

> When we die (humans), so will Mother Nature. Mother Nature is a name we've given to someone that doesn't exist. When humans die, so will the concept of a Mother Nature looking out over all nature.

Comment: You did it! YAY!!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> [Africanized honey bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africanized_bee)

At first we feared her.

> We feared her because we want to get honey.

Now she fears us, the killers.

> She want to protect their queen and so attack us and sting us.

We'll die together.

> Her venom is killer, so we will die. And she [will die](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110413084717AAoZ569) after stinging.